# What is the cardinality of the 'writes' relationship type?

Tags: database, relationship, cardinality, entity-relationship

What is the cardinality of the `writes` relationship type?

a) One-to-many

b) Many-to-many

c) One-to-one

d) None of the other options

This question confuses me a lot. This is all the context that is given in the question.

I think it can be One-to-many, for example, 1 person can write more than one letter. But it can be Many-to-many, for example, A person writes many books. And one book is also written by many people. It can also be One-to-one.

So would it be none of the other options since it is not necessary that every author has written more than one book? Or  should it be all of the options?
Am I correct in thinking d) is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may be confused by the fact that the **cardinality** in the **set theory** refers to the number of elements in one instance of the set, and as you pointed out in your examples, there are different possible cases.

The term **cardinality** in **Entity-Relationship modeling** refers to the possible boundaries of the entity sets on each side. (This is why the UML terminology avoids the “cardinality” term and uses ***multiplicity***).

So in your E/R model, the kind of relationship depends on the maximal “cardinality” that is **possible** on both sides. Considering:

> It can be Many-to-many, for example, A person writes many books. And one book is also written by many people.

The answer would therefore be b. If your model lr your database relation can represent many-to-many, it includes all the other possibilities. If you’d chose another option, you could only deal with a subset of the possible cases because you’d not be able to deal with many to many.